# 2D MATRIX statement for 5 x 5 Grid

Tags: arrays, recursion, multidimensional-array, dynamic-programming

Given a 5 x 5 Grid comprising of tiles numbered from 1 to 25 and a set of 5 start-end point pairs. 
For each pair,find a path from the start point to the end point. 
The paths should meet the below conditions:

a) Only Horizontal and Vertical moves allowed.

b) No two paths should overlap.

c) Paths should cover the entire grid

Input consist of 5 lines. 
Each line contains two space-separated integers,Starting and Ending point.

Output: Print 5 lines. Each line consisting of space-separated integers,the path for the corresponding start-end pair. Assume that such a path Always exists. In case of Multiple Solution,print any one of them.

Sample Input

1 22

4 17

5 18

9 13

20 23

Sample Output

1 6 11 16 21 22

4 3 2 7 12 17

5 10 15 14 19 18

9 8 13

20 25 24 23

Comment: Please show what have you tried and why it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

i think there should be restriction or it lacks some more information about the input ( start point and endpoint)
because if we take following input then covering whole grid is not possible
1 22,
6 7,
11 12,
16 17,
8 9

Comment: This seems better suitable as comment than as answer