# Finding Path between elements of a grid

Tags: java

Plz help me with this question i am unable to do it

> Given a 5 x 5 Grid comprising of tiles numbered from 1 to 25 and a set of 5 start-end point pairs. 
>   For each pair,find a path from the start point to the end point. 
>   The paths should meet the below conditions:
>   a) Only Horizontal and Vertical moves allowed.
>   b) No two paths should overlap.
>   c) Paths should cover the entire grid
>
> Input:
>   Input consist of 5 lines. 
>   Each line contains two space-separated integers,Starting and Ending point.
>
> Output:
>   Print 5 lines. Each line consisting of space-separated integers,the path for the corresponding start-end pair. 
>   Assume that such a path Always exists. 
>   In case of Multiple Solution,print any one of them.
>
> Sample Input
>
> ```
> 1 22 
> 4 17 
> 5 18 
> 9 13 
> 20 23
> ```
>
> Sample Output
>
> ```
> 1 6 11 16 21 22 
> 4 3 2 7 12 17 
> 5 10 15 14 19 18 
> 9 8 13 
> 20 25 24 23
> ```

Comment: uhm... can you show us a drawing of whats supposed to happen?

Comment: duplicate of [on hold] thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31096566/all-paths-between-two-nodes-of-an-grid-structure-using-java

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31082704/java-non-overlapping-paths-between-n-start-and-n-end-points

Comment: and of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31098661/2d-matrix-statement-for-5-x-5-grid

Comment: Your question is very broad and unclear. You need to describe in more detail what kind of help you need, what part of this assignment is unclear and [what have you tried to solve it](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have the logic of the solution.  You will need to do the coding yourself (or at least TRY to do it, I can further help if you get stuck, but I will not post complete code!)

The trick is to find a start-end pair where both are on "edges" of the matrix.
For example, the pairs `1 22` and `20 23` are such pairs.
Once you find such a pair (any one will do) you plot the path along the edge/s.

Then, the edges of the matrix need to be re-calculated to reflect the plotted path so once you plotted `1 22` numbers 7,12,17 becomes edge numbers (since numbers 6,11,16 were removed)

After that, you will see that the pair `4 17` becomes "on edge" and the process can repeat until all pairs are accounted for.

EDIT:
After dry running on the pair `5 18` I see that "being on edge" includes diagonal position:

```
xxxxX
xxxxx
xxxAx
xxxx*
xx***
```

This is the matrix status after plotting pair `20 23`. Position A is "on the edge" because its south-east (bottom right) corner is now outside the matrix.

Comment: but the matrix won't be regular everytime??

Comment: yes sorry i mean it will be jagged, and i have to find edges in it

Comment: yes, it wil be jagged, your "find edge" algorithm will have to be updated as you plot pairs.  Also, dry run on the pair `5 18` and you will see that being on edge includes diagonal position (see edited answer)

Comment: just stumbled upon yet another duplicate, this one contains multiple answers and much more info http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31080969/approximation-algorithm-for-non-intersecting-paths-in-a-grid